# BrotherBard's GitX won't load a certain repo

Tags: git, gitx

I am trying to use BrotherBard's excellent fork of [Gitx](https://github.com/brotherbard/gitx/), on a certain repo. It works on all other repo's but just will not load this one. It seems to be a valid repo, and terminal access is fine.

---

To clarify: It won't open. The window doesn't open, nothing happens. All over repo's on my local machine load fine

---

**EDIT** *Added Console Logs*

Here are the console logs

```
    21/06/2011 09:49:21 GitX[14750] Could not connect the action discussGitX: to target of class ApplicationController
    21/06/2011 09:49:21 GitX[14750] Error loading /Library/InputManagers/Ecamm/Ecamm Plugin Loader.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Ecamm Plugin Loader:  dlopen(/Library/InputManagers/Ecamm/Ecamm Plugin Loader.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Ecamm Plugin Loader, 265): no suitable image found.  Did find:
        /Library/InputManagers/Ecamm/Ecamm Plugin Loader.bundle/Contents/MacOS/Ecamm Plugin Loader: GC capability mismatch
21/06/2011 09:49:46 GitX[14750] *** -[NSCFDictionary setObject:forKey:]: attempt to insert nil key
```

Comment: Migrated to SO as requested by @MildFuzz

Comment: Maybe related to [issue #63](https://github.com/laullon/gitx/issues/63), quoting: Try running the following command and see if you get an error:
git for-each-ref --format='%(refname) %(objecttype) %(objectname) %(*objectname)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Laullon fork](https://github.com/laullon/gitx/downloads), less buggy and has more features than brotherboard's version.

Comment: I'm not sure how to distinguish this repo from others.

Comment: Can you post the repo on github? any console message?

Comment: added console messages to question body, but can't post to github for copywrite/ownership issues.

Answer (score 0):

Cloning the repo fixed this for me.

Comment: Move over to Source Control. Much better